# FLASH AS3: Delete keyframes programmatically

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, actionscript, slideshow

**Here's what i'm trying to do:**
I have a slideshow of pictures with a simple fading transition. I do not have the source file and i'd like to extract all of the single pictures from the slideshow. I've imported the video into flash so that all of the images from the video are keyframes.

So now, I have a movie with about 10,000 keyframes. I have a known interval of keyframes that I do not want (when the picture is on a frame by itself and it's not transitioning with another picture).

**Can I:**

1. Delete an interval of keyframes
2. Create a new movieclip/document/scene... with the keyframes that I want

Any suggestions would be very helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy keyframes like you want to do, but I can offer you a way to play your movie/movieclip without unwanted frames.

First you should add an event listener on EnterFrame:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
```

Then you may write a method to define your valid frames:

```
private function isValidFrame(frameIndex:uint):Boolean
{
    return frameIndex > 10       //range start
            && frameIndex < 3000 //range end 
            && [62, 15, 337].indexOf(frameIndex) == -1;//add forbidden frames here
}
```

And finaly, you can write your enterframe listener:

```
private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{
    var frameIndex:uint = this.currentFrame;
    while (!isValidFrame(frameIndex))
    {
        frameIndex++;
        if (frameIndex >= 10000)
        {
            //stop everything
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }
    }
    gotoAndStop(frameIndex);
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to delete the keyframes? you could just go to the exact keyframe you want and make a bitmap copy from the movieclip at that frame.
Here follows a little util class I buod to make bitmap copies from DisplayObjects:

```
package{
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.geom.Point;

public final class Cropper{

    public function Cropper():void{}

    public static function crop(_x, _y, _w:Number, _h:Number, displayObject:DisplayObject):Bitmap
    {
        var cropArea:Rectangle = new Rectangle(_x, _y, _w, _h);
        var croppedBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(_w, _h, true, 0x00000000));

        var dispObjData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(displayObject.width, displayObject.height, true, 0x00000000);
        dispObjData.draw(displayObject);

        croppedBitmap.bitmapData.copyPixels(dispObjData, cropArea, new Point(0, 0), null, null, true);

        return croppedBitmap;
    }
}
```

}

And you could use it on a loop to iterate on an keyframe array and make the copies, ± like this:

```
var arr:Array = new Array(1, 10, 20, 30, 40...);
for(var i:int = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
yourDisplayObject.gotoAndStop(arr[i]);
var cropPic:Bitmap = Cropper.crop(x, y, width, height, displayObjectToCopy);
}
```

tell me if it works for you...